# Convert EST time to local Time in java

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, simpledateformat

I'm unable to convert (12/19/2012 8:57am EST) to local Time (now Indian Time). 
While converting I'm getting wrong time (Dec 19 2012 11:27). I'm using the following code:

```
private void convertEdtToLocalTime(String pubDate)
{
    //pubDate = 12/19/2012 8:57am EST;
    String localPubDate;
    try
    {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mma z");
        TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
        sdf.setTimeZone(timeZone);
        if (pubDate != null)
        {
            Date date = sdf.parse(pubDate);
            sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy HH:mm");
            localPubDate = sdf.format(date);
        }
    }
    catch (ParseException e)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: What would be the correct time?

Comment: Dec 19 2012 19:30 (indian Time).

Comment: @GvSrinivas: Are you sure that your system default time zone is really Indian time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to set the timeZone as the the time zone is already specified in the pubDate string. When you want to format using different SDF, the default timezone will convert it into default timezone itself. For eg. if you are in india, IST time = Dec 19 2012 19:27

```
private static  void convertEdtToLocalTime(String pubDate)
    {
        //pubDate = 12/19/2012 8:57am EST;
        String localPubDate=null;
        try
        {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mma z");
//          TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault(); // No need to do it
//          sdf.setTimeZone(timeZone);
            if (pubDate != null)
            {
                Date date = sdf.parse(pubDate);
                sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy HH:mm");
                localPubDate = sdf.format(date);
            }
        }
        catch (ParseException e)
        {
        }
        System.out.println(localPubDate);
    }
```

Comment: actually i have to get user time zone and convert EST time to Users local time.

Comment: where will this code be executed ?? users machine ?? then it will give the time local to users timezone.

Comment: yeah.it will be executed on users machine(anywhere across the globe). is it not required to get the users timezone?

Comment: sdf.format(date); will format in users local timezone if no other timezone is specified